# QGIS 3.22.16 URL does not want to open. Unable to Get Local Issuer Certificate

Tags: url, qgis, wms, wfs

I am trying to get some data from this website. https://maps.allerdale.gov.uk/allerdale.aspx. I clicked on the option "add WFS layer and pasted this link into the URL. When I clicked on connect I got this message.
(Image). I am not sure if WFS is the right option though. Any idea on how to get this data loaded?

[image: ERROR MESSAGE]

I tried the option add WMS/WMTS  and add WFS/OGC API. I was expecting to get the data instead an error message appears.